# How high could i jump if I weighed only half as much?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

E.g.

I weigh 150 lbs

I had a thrust device that lifted 75 pounds.

How high could I jump?

What if that thrust lifted 2/3 of my weight (100 lbs)?

Obviously, I cant fly, but I guarantee if I weighed 75 lbs less, I could jump a lot higher than I currently can.

Comment: Assuming that you only lost fat?

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously, I cant fly, but I guarantee if I weighed 75 lbs less, I
>   could jump a lot higher than I currently can.

Thank you. I appreciate your guarantee.

> How high could i jump if I weighed only half as much?

Under the assumption that you would be able to impart the same amount of energy with your legs, you would be able to jump twice as high. Because
$$
mgh=(\frac{m}{2})g(2h)\;.
$$

...Not sure if this is an appropriate assumption for your case.

Comment: Yes. You might want to add that "same amount of energy" is the right approach because the distance your legs move is the same, and so is the force. And work done is $F\cdot x$. All that kinetic energy becomes potential energy at this new greater height. Note - this approach is valid if you really are lighter - it's not obvious that it's true if you have a 75 lb thrust added.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean you can use your thrust device *further to* the thrust you can impart with your own legs. Otherwise, something can lift 75 pound weight won't lift you at all.

Also, you need to explain how your thrust device's force changes as you move (a spring, for example, imparts less force the more it relaxes).

So I'll assume your device is something that can impart a *constant* force on you as you jump off the ground and fall back. This, as you imply, is equivalent to having the same thrust capability in your legs when you weigh half your current weight. So now you are solving the DE (here $x$ is the height co-ordinate):

$$F = m\,\ddot{x}= f(x) + T - m\,g \Leftrightarrow \ddot{x} = \frac{1}{m}\,(f(x)+T)-g\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}_x v^2 = \frac{1}{m}\,(f(x)+T)-g$$

where $f(x)$ models the thrust of your legs as you rise of the ground, and it falls to nought after some height $h_0$ when your feet lose contact with the ground. We also assume $v=0$ when you begin. $T$ models the constant thrust of your thrusting device. So now you explore the above with different values of $T$: $f(x)$ is constant. You reach your maximum height $h_{max}$ when $v^2 = 0$. So you must solve:

$$\int_0^{h_{max}} (f(x)+T)\,\mathrm{d}\,x - m\,g\,h_{max} = 0$$

Assuming you can jump off the ground without help, you know $h_{max}>h_0$ *i.e.* you can at least reach a point where your legs are fully stretched out and you are leaving the ground, so that the first term in your integral must be the constant $E=\int_0^{h_0} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\,x$. $J$ represents your unhelped, "intrinsic" jumping capability. It is the *energy* your legs impart. So now you explore the equation:

$$E+(T-m\,g)\,h_{max}=0$$

where $m$ is your mass, as a function of $T$ (you can also get this equation from energy considerations). Assuming you know how high you can jump $h_u$ without help, *i.e.* with $T=0$, you can use this knowledge to solve the above equation for $E$, and thus get the relationship you want.

Comment: Seems uncharacteristically complicated?

Answer (score 0):

This answer looks at what happens to your jump height if you actually decrease in mass, while maintaining the same leg jump strength.

So, let us assume that the mechanism by which a person jumps can be modelled as a finite impulse that occurs in an instance (i.e. a very very large force applied in a short frame of time). Let this impulse has a magnitude $I$, and let the original mass of the jumping body be $m_0$. I'll assume the size of the impulse stays the same regardless of the mass.

So, when you apply this impulse to a body at rest, with mass $m$, you instantly increase the upward momentum by $I$. Therefore, the body will leave the ground with velocity equal to $I/m_0$.

Now, we can make use of one of the 1D constant-acceleration equations of motion, because the only consider force the body will experience in the air is a constant gravitational force, which causes a constant downward acceleration of $g$. Let's use the equation:
$$v^2 = u^2 + 2as$$
where $v$ is the final velocity, $u$ is initial velocity, $a$ is the constant acceleration, and $s$ is the change in displacement.

Taking our sign convention to be positive upwards, let $a = -g$, $v = 0$ (as max height is reached when the body become instantaneously stationary in mid air), and $s = h$, where $h$ is the max height reached.

$$0 = u^2 - 2gh$$

We already found that $u = I/m$, so:
$$2gh = I^2/m^2$$
$$I^2 = 2ghm^2$$

$I$ is constant, so we can write an equation relating the original mass, $m_0$ and original jump height, $h_0$, to the new mass, $m_{new}$ and new jump height $h_{new}$:

$$2gh_0 m^2_0 = 2gh_{new}m_{new}^2$$
$$\therefore h_{new} = h_0 \frac{m_0^2}{m_{new}^2}$$

So, for example, if you original weight 150lbs, and you could originally jump 1m, reducing you weight to 75lbs would increase your new jump height to 4m. If your weight was now 100lbs, you could jump 2.25m high.

More realistically, if you lose 10lbs, then your new jump height in this example would be 1.15m, a 15cm increase in height!

Comment: This is based on a faulty assumption. You are assuming $F\Delta t$ is constant, but if you are lighter, $\Delta t$ will be shorter and unless your muscles got stronger, you are unlikely to be able to maintain the impulse against a lower mass.

Comment: Ok, I see. Goes to show the shortcomings of an assumption! How come, though, $\Delta t$ gets shorter with a decrease in mass? Also, does that still matter if the impulse occurs instantaneously (infinitesimal $\Delta t$, delta function $F$)? Is that an unreasonable assumption in this case?

Comment: If you have the same force, but lower mass, the acceleration will be greater. The time to go from "crouch" to "lift off" (same distance for light and heavy you) will be reduced since $x = \frac12 a t^2$

Comment: Makes sense! I'll amend my answer with this once I find time to. Thanks!